# Laravel: whereIn with variable

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel, where-in

I'm trying to collect all the records that belong to the sections that happen to them in the variable $sections. But only those from section 1 pick me up. Any suggestions?

```
$sections = '1,2,3';

$data = News::where('active', '1')
        ->whereIn('section_id', [$sections])
        ->get();
```

If I substitute $sections in the query for the values, this works, but if I use the variable $sections, It doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use `whereIn()` you must pass an array and not string:

```
$sections = explode(',', '1,2,3');
```

Comment: He'd better $sections = [1,2,3];

Comment: @Amarnasan it's just an example. I don't think OP hardcodes these categories, but getting these from the request as a string or something.

Comment: Amarnasan, I tried it in the way you indicated earlier but I only got those from the first section. The answer from Alexey works correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your $sections variable is a string. And you are passing that string to the array, not each individual numbers in the string.

Ex:

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->whereIn('id', [1, 2, 3])
                ->get();
```